# Postman requests in same session

Tags: api, postman

I'm experimenting with the TeamCity API with Postman. When doing `POST` and `PUT` requests, you're required to supply `Authorize` header with a token that's permanent, and also a `X-TC-CSRF-Token` header, that has to be requested in a previous call.

This works fine in for example Powershell. But in Postman I get 403 because the CSRF tokens doesn't match. According to the documentation:

> When considering HTTP request safety from the TeamCity perspective, the following checks are sequentially made:
>
> 1. If an HTTP request has a secure CSRF token either in the parameter or in the HTTP header and this token matches the one stored in user session, it is considered safe.
> 2. If an HTTP request is a non-modifying one (such as GET ), it is
>    considered safe.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/csrf-protection.html#CSRF+checks+for+HTTP+request)

My guess is that it fails on user session not being the same in both Postman requests. Even though I've set it up in a pre-request script. Or maybe cookie related as noted [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/csrf-protection.html#CSRF+checks+for+HTTP+request).

I've looked around Postman settings but haven't found anything obvious to change. Any ideas?